# Binomial distribution for a poll

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm looking for help with this question on the binomial distribution.

`An election shows that the winning candidate receives 46% of the votes. What is the probability that a poll of (a) 200 people, (b) 1000 people, selected at random from voters shows a majority supporting the candidate.`

My best effort for the 200 case goes as follows:

By the CLT, X~N(0.46,$\sigma^2/n$)

X~N($0.46,\sqrt\frac{0.46(1-0.46)}{200}$)

t-stat= $\frac{0.50-0.46}{0.03524}=1.135$

p-value= 2 $\phi(1.135)$=0.1271

**I cannot reconcile my answer** with [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability%20that%20X%3E100%20given%20that%20X~B%28200%2C0.46%29) result from Wolfram Alpha

I also cannot reconcile it with this approach, which I think should be equally valid:

By the CLT, X~N(92,$\sigma^2/n$)

X~N($92,\sqrt\frac{200*0.46(1-0.46)}{200}$)=X~N($92,0.498$)

t-stat= $\frac{92-100}{0.498}=16.1$

p-value= 2x $\phi(16.1)$=0.00001

Answer (score 1):

For part (a),
$$P(X>100) = \sum_{k=101}^{200} \binom{200}{k}(.46)^k(.54)^{200-k} \approx .1140395$$
is the value from wolfram alpha. Similarly, for part (b),
$$P(X>500) = \sum_{k=501}^{1000} \binom{1000}{k}(.46)^k(.54)^{1000-k} \approx .0051416$$